# Security Exception: MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: socket during opening JNLP file

Tags: java, windows-7, jnlp, java-web-start, malformedurlexception

OS: Windows 7 32-bit
JDK: jdk1.7.0_25

I have Studio.jnlp file. I tried to open it by double-click. But I found the error as below:

"MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: socket"
Details: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: socket

[image: Summary of Exception]

[image: Details of Exception]

Comment: What is the (presumably malformed) URL? Post code, error messages and stack trace; not pictures.

Comment: In my case I just had to disable the proxy on... Firefox (as it is my primary browser)!

Comment: For linux users it is a jcontrol program: https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/javanetmalformedurlexception-unknown-protocol-socket-console-sep-121

Answer (score 26):

Go to Control Panel of Windows and do the followings:

Click Java -> Click "Network Settings..." button under General tab -> Select Direct connection radio -> Click OK

That's it. Exception could be removed.

Comment: The question is which "browser setting" is used on Linux as default?

Comment: Good point keiki. Running linux here. I had proxy set up in Firefox but was launching the JNLP app from chrome and this error was a mystery to me.

Comment: Works well with linux too.

Comment: how do we do this on mac?

Comment: If you are in Linux Run command `ControlPanel` and Go to `General` > `Network Settings..` > `Direct Connection`

Answer (score 2):

This message comes from the use of a proxy server which is not fully set in Internet options (in Internet Explorer).

When a proxy server is set manually, but with the option "use this server for all protocols", Internet Explorer does not fill the "Socks" protocol field with it.

Direct connection works, because you bypass this proxy configuration set in IE. But another way to fix this is to uncheck "use this server for all protocols", and instead paste it in the socks field as well.

It should solve the issue without having to bypass the proxy for all Java programs.

---

However, this is assuming that your proxy server knows what to do with this protocol, and how to direct it to the correct place. If it doesn't, then you are probably better off trying direct connection.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, this error can be shown when proxy settings are configured in the desktop's system settings. E.g. "systemsettings" in KDE/Plasma.

jdk comes with a configuration GUI called ControlPanel. Run this from a terminal inside your desktop, select "Network Settings", and fill out the form according to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `javaws --viewer` to open the Java Control Panel, click on the button `Network Settings` and select `Direct Connection`.

Now run again your jnlp with:
`javaws Studio.jnlp`